# Help with deleting in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to delete everything up to the cursor or after the cursor or everything but selected text.

Comment: Do you mean interactively, or in an elisp program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want sounds a pretty infrequent thing to be done, but here are a few ways to do it:

First, put cursor on start of text you want to keep. Press <kbd>C-space</kbd> to set mark. Then, use <kbd>M-<</kbd> (`beginning-of-buffer`) and afterwards <kbd>C-w</kbd> (`kill-region-x`). Now, everything before text is deleted.

Next, go to end of text and set mark once again with <kbd>C-space</kbd>. Now, go to end of buffer with <kbd>M-></kbd> and once again delete everything with <kbd>C-w</kbd>.

This is one way to do it.

Other way is to simply copy selected text and put it into new buffer. I'll leave it to you as an exercise.

Comment: M-< and M-> not working. M-SHIFT-< doesn't work too. But typing beginning-of-buffer manually works. Why M-< doesn't work on my PC?

Comment: @pic11: I'd suggest reading [this article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeybindingGuide) on Emacs keybinding.

Comment: Try Esc-<, Esc->. Ctrl-Home/Ctrl-End should do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Everything after "the cursor" (aka "point") is deleted using `C-k` (`kill-line`). To kill the line *up to* point, give a 0 argument like this: `C-u 0 C-k`.

I don't know if there's a way to kill only things that aren't selected. Maybe some kind of "invert-region" before hand?

Answer (score 4):

To keep only the selected text:

```
C-w C-x h C-w C-y M-y
```

In other words, kill the selection, select what remains, kill that, then yank the previous selection.